# fprintf and asterisk pyramid

Tags: c, file

I really need some help here, I've been going at this for 6 hours now and I feel like I've tried everything I can. Here is what I need to do:

I need to print an asterisk pyramid to a `triangle2.txt` file in C.

I know the code I have inside will create a pyramid (changed all the `fprintf` statements to `printf` and it works perfectly), but for some reason when I run the file as it is, it only generates one `*` and a blank line underneath.

Please let me know what you think, I've been going back and forth with my teacher and I can't seem to get it. Thank you.

```
int main() {
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int i, space, rows, k = 0; 
    ptr_file = fopen("Triangle2.txt", "w");

    if (!ptr_file) return 1;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0) {

        for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
            fprintf(ptr_file, "  ");
        }

        while (k != 2 * i - 1) {
            fprintf(ptr_file, "* ");
            ++k;
        }

        fprintf(ptr_file, "\n");
    } 

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this is my first post so I may be doing this wrong

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see it has no indentation. This is considered un-good.

Comment: so I'm going to just get downvoted into oblivion because I'm not sure what I need to do? I'm genuinely coming here for help and input to learn.

Comment: Following the advice given will help you not get downvotes. Remember that you are asking people for free help in their spare time, so it's best to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: I don't know how to follow the advice, it's very vague. can anyone clarify

Comment: To clarify, you are saying that you do not know what indentation is? Or something else?

Comment: I can randomly indent for sure, but I feel like thats not whats being asked for

Comment: No, I don't believe anyone asked you to _randomly_ indent. I believe the word Pablo used was "properly". Put some indentation into your code (typically, one level of indentation per block level) so that we can actually read it.

Comment: Is that how it should be?

Comment: Much better, thank you. Now I will take a look at it.

Comment: Tip: Insure `scanf("%d",&rows);` worked as expected.  Try `if(scanf("%d",&rows) == 1) printf("%d\n", rows); else return 1;`

Comment: I have modified it to work in isolation, and to be C++ (because I'm more comfortable with that), and [it seems to work just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f120d96b08459970). This suggests the problem is not in your program logic.

Comment: Works just fine as unmodified C, as well

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I hadn't actually spotted the question was tagged C else I'd probably have left it ^_^

Comment: OP it's quite a nice implementation too. [Wheeeeee](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4123980c852b38a)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think that was the problem. That txt file wasn't updating so I deleted and renamed to triangle3 and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Bet that's annoying after 6 hours. For future reference it's _always_ beneficial to break down your program into chunks when you have a problem like this. See how I replaced the use of a file with simple writing to `stdout`? And replaced the user input with a hard-coded number? It worked, so that _immediately_ told us where to look for the problem! Divide and conquer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine as posted, the problem was elsewhere, in the file system.

Here are some remarks on your code:

- you must include `<stdio.h>`
- you should test return value of `scanf()`.
- you should use a classic `for` loop to print the stars. As posted, you initialize `k` in various unexpected places.
- In C, it is customary to use zero based index values and use `<` instead of `<=` for the end test.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int rows, i, space, k;

    ptr_file = fopen("Triangle2.txt", "w");
    if (!ptr_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open Triangle2.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (space = i + 1; space < rows; space++) {
            fprintf(ptr_file, "  ");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * i + 1; k++) {
            fprintf(ptr_file, "* ");
        }
        fprintf(ptr_file, "\n");
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```